# is there no needs three or more binary operations for constructing(?)algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

In Algebra class, professor metioned godel proved no three or more operation be needed in algebra. if he is right where can i get the proof.

if you can't get it, Sorry for my short english..

Comment: hope someone knows what your teacher meant (from your rather terse description), but it might be best to ask your teacher for a clarification.